# Apache Multiple Rewrite Rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a 2 sets of rewrite rules. This is the Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName datingjapan.co
    ServerAlias *.datingjapan.co
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/datingjapan.co
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have been trying to add the .htaccess to the Virtual Host so I can remove the .htaccess file - below is an example, but I get the site to show:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName datingjapan.co
    ServerAlias *.datingjapan.co
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/datingjapan.co
</VirtualHost>
```

I understand the [L] means last rule to match so I have removed that but it still doesn't work.

What am I missing here? I've tried reversing the rules.

thankyou

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`L` will still be needed as Last flag is for marking end of each rewrite rule. Ordering of rules is also important. Change your code to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName datingjapan.co
    ServerAlias *.datingjapan.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/datingjapan.co

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be 2 [L] flag on the .htaccess body.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#for the purpose of multiple rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#for the purpose of multiple rewrite rules (usage of multiple L flag)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```