# apache http redirect to https multiple rewriteconditions

Tags: apache, ssl, https, virtualhost

I am very new to changing apache settings and modifying httpd.conf.  I have installed an SSL and am attempting to redirect dynamic subdomains to HTTPS.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName catchall.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/places/

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /places/index.php?request=$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName catchall.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/places/
    SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /SUPERSECRET
SSLCertificateKeyFile /SUPERSECRET
SSLCertificateChainFile /SUPERSECRET
</VirtualHost>
```

If I went to example.mydomain.com  the page does load properly, but it does not redirect the HTTPS.  I have tried multiple variations of changing where the rewrite conditions and rules are placed and I am restarting my httpd service after I make changes.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching stackoverflow more and more, I was able to narrow down what my problem was.

[Apache Multiple Rewrite Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142971/apache-multiple-rewrite-rules)

anubhava kindly points out "L will still be needed as Last flag is for marking end of each rewrite rule. Ordering of rules is also important. "

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /places/index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

This is the correct format now.  I hope this helps someone else.